# Fetching Multiple Images from Database into PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, windows, picturebox

I want to fetch multiple images from my database, where `data` is the field for image. Here is my code, but it shows only the first picture. Please Help.

```
SqlConnection sq = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-GH3KCDH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Project1;User ID=sa;Password=Salma0300.");
String st = "select data FROM Picture";
sq.Open();
PictureBox[] pb = { pictureBox1,pictureBox2,pictureBox3,pictureBox4,pictureBox5,pictureBox6,pictureBox7,pictureBox8};

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(st, sq);
    byte[] image = (byte[])sqlcom.ExecuteScalar();
    stream.Write(image,0,image.Length);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
    pb[1].Image = bitmap;
    pb[2].Image = bitmap;
```

Comment: You need to use a loop.

Comment: ExecuteScalar only returns the first column of the first row, so you are only asking for one image.

Comment: @LarsTech yeah but i didn't find any other way

Comment: @SeanO'Neil but how i did try but nothing happened :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues.

#### Only grabbing 1 image even though you selected the entire table.

```
byte[] image = (byte[])sqlcom.ExecuteScalar();
```

You need to iterate through the rows. Use `ExecuteReader()` instead of `ExecuteScalar` in order to get a `SqlDataReader` object. Then continue calling `Read()` from the reader until you have no more records or no more picture boxes to fill.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

#### You are only working with a single bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
pb[1].Image = bitmap;
pb[2].Image = bitmap;
```

See the problem? You loaded up a single `bitmap` and are setting your boxes to the exact same image. Iterating through all of the records mentioned above should inherently allow you to see the issue and correct this.

Comment: No problem. The MSDN documentation I linked has a good example of using the SqlDataReader down at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I am sorry but i still did'nt get that